# Is it safe to connect 3kV with the +Vout pin of RECOM RM-1209S

Tags: current-measurement, safety, high-voltage

I have a current sensing circuit which is used to measure the current from **3KV** supply. The distance between the pins of the DC-DC converter is too small so I want to know that is it appropriate and safe (in a sense to avoid sparks etc) to **connect 3kV or 2kV with the 9V output pin** of **RM-1209S**?

Pin1 --> 12V and 3kV GND.

Pin2 --> 12VDC.

Pin3 --> 9VGND (isolated).

Pin4 --> 3kV

[image]

The link of circuit that i am following is down below:

Here i am using 3kV instead of 1kV and generating 9VDC through RM-1209S.

[image]
https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/1867

Comment: Connect 3kV to +Vout????

Comment: The [Datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/468/RM-958360.pdf) tells you that device only has an isolation rating of 1kVdc - so No.

Comment: The RM-0505S will not survive 12V in, and it will never give 9V out. It's isolation is also not rated for 3kV peaks at all.

Comment: This silly question should be closed.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. The RM-0505S module is not compatible with the in and output voltages you mention.

Comment: Don't play around with 3 kV if you don't know what you are doing. It will get you killed. VTC.

Answer (score 2):

The isolation voltage for the H suffix RECOM RM-0505S is 2 kV so no, it's almost certainly not safe to connect the output voltage to a 3 kV power supply line. Read the data sheet.

Comment: Sorry Andy aka for any inconvenience. What if I am using 2kV, will it work then??

Comment: @SabheehAli let me make this clear - you have edited the question to change 3 kV to 2 kV and this makes my answer look stupid so, do the right thing and put it back to 3 kV or someone coming along is going to down vote my answer thinking I can't read properly and no, 2 kV is still no good because that is a 1 second test limit and not a long term operational withstand voltage. READ THE DATA SHEET AND FIX YOUR QUESTION.

Comment: What if i use IHA0112D09

Comment: It certainly looks more appropriate for DC voltages up to 6 kV but I would want XP to confirm what the DC working voltage is. They say the AC working voltage is only 250 V and this concerns me that the DC working voltage might only be 500 volts. The devil is in the detail and a lot of data sheets will use impressive figures where the small print is really small!